# VBA Macro: Merging two columns into 1

Tags: excel, vba

I've checked all the answers in stackoverflow about merging cells in excel using macro, but I'm having a hard time understanding the codes.

Description:
I want to MERGE the two cells which contains "Lastname" and "Firstname" into one cell in row 3.

Thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub MerThem()
    Set r = Range("3:3").Find(what:="Lastname", After:=Range("3:3")(1))

    v = r.Value & r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    r.Clear
    r.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).MergeCells = True
    r.Value = v
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]